getting min and max value to create data chunks
This is further to a question asked :
SQL: How would you split a 100,000 records from a Oracle table into 5 chunks?
The percentile solution works most of the time but some time I don't get the values in the correct order which creates problem which using them to chunk the data, below is my query and its result:
SELECT batch_number, MIN(trxn_no), MAX(trxn_no) - 1, COUNT(1) AS batch_size
  FROM (SELECT trxn_no, NTILE(15) OVER (ORDER BY trxn_no) AS batch_number
          FROM processed_trxns)
 GROUP BY batch_number
 ORDER BY batch_number;

  1 1                  2028014   13978092
  2 2028015            2693634   13978091
  3 2693635            3171854   13978091
  4 3171855            3433231   13978091
**5 3433232             371815   13978091**
  6 371816             4080200   13978091
  7 4080201            4566643   13978091
  8 4566644            4983410   13978091
  9 4983411            5463275   13978091
 10 5463276            5947051   13978091
 11 5947052            6595154   13978091
 12 6595155            7271102   13978091
 13 7271104            8035539   13978091
 14 8035540            8852157   13978091
 15 8852158            9999998   13978091

the highlighted batch number (batch 5) shows max trxn_no lower than min trxn_no. why this is happening?
the expexted results should be like this instead

   1 1           201262   13992990
   2 201263     2693256   13992990
   3 2693257        3171596   13992990
   4 3171597        3432904   13992990
   5 3432905        3718367   13992989
   6 3718368        4080955   13992989
   7 4080956        4567284   13992989
   8 4567285        4984142   13992989
   9 4984143        5464390   13992989
  10 5464391        5948080   13992989
  11 5948081        6596460   13992989
  12 6596461        7272562   13992989
  13 7272563        8036943   13992989
  14 8036944        8853310   13992989
  15 8853311        9999998   13992989


Beside the sorting issue, I think I see a flaw in the approach. You use MAX(trxn_no) - 1, and I suppose this is because trxn_no occur multiple times in the table and you want each chunk to have exclusive numbers. In your expected output you don't want block #4 to include 3432905, because block #5 includes it, too. By subtracting one from the maximum transaction number you kind of move this last number to the next block, but this means 1. your count is not correct, and 2. you can lose numbers. Block #12 in the original output ends on 7271102, block #13 starts with 7271104. Is 7271103 missing?

Chunking like this can often lead to performance problems due to overloading I/O on the database. You may want instead to consider hash partitioning the table. Then you can use extended partition naming to have each thread pull from one partition only, and leave the distribution function of data to Oracle.

@ThorstenKettner
This missing no number in 12th block I have also noticed and my reason to do -1 from the max trxn_no is absolutely what you have mentioned, what should be the approach to chunking the data?

@PaulW
I don't have control over this table and asking the owners to do this partitioning is going to be another nightmare, what should be the approach to chunking the data?

@Abhay Singh: It makes little sense to think of another approach, as long as we don't understand whats going wrong with the current approach. Only when this is understood and solved should we think about the next step.

I've removed the tag psql, because this request is not about the PostgreSQL terminal shell. I've added sql instead.

Best guess: check the data type of the trxn_no. If it is VARCHAR2 and you want to sort is numerically, you ought to sort with ORDER BY to_number(trxn_no)

the data type is Number

Either use TO_NUMBER, so you are comparing the values as numbers:
SELECT batch_number,
       MIN(trxn_no),
       MAX(trxn_no) - 1,
       COUNT(1) AS batch_size
FROM   (
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(trxn_no) AS trxn_no,
         NTILE(15) OVER (ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(trxn_no)) AS batch_number
  FROM   processed_trxns
)
GROUP BY batch_number
ORDER BY batch_number;

or LPAD, to ensure the strings are all the same length:
SELECT batch_number,
       MIN(trxn_no),
       MAX(trxn_no) - 1,
       COUNT(1) AS batch_size
FROM   (
  SELECT LPAD(trxn_no, 8, '0') AS trxn_no,
         NTILE(15) OVER (ORDER BY LPAD(trxn_no, 8, '0')) AS batch_number
  FROM   processed_trxns
)
GROUP BY batch_number
ORDER BY batch_number;

(But that would give you leading zeroes in the output)

Your column trxn_no is obviously a string column. '1' < '2...', '34...' < '37...', '37...' < '40...', no matter what the strings' lengths are. At last you subtract 1 from the maximum trxn_no, which is possible, because the strings contain numbers that Oracle can convert implicitly.



MIN(TRXN_NO)
MAX(TRXN_NO) - 1




1
2028014


2028015
2693634


2693635
3171854


3171855
3433231


3433232
371815


371816
4080200


4080201
4566643


4566644
4983410


...
...



If you want to store numbers, use a numeric column for this. My advice hence is: change the table column's data type. If this is no possible, cast:
WITH
  corrected AS (SELECT TO_NUMBER(trxn_no) AS trxn_numeric FROM processed_trxns)
SELECT 
  batch_number,
  MIN(trxn_numeric), 
  MAX(trxn_numeric) - 1, 
  COUNT(*) AS batch_size
FROM 
(
  SELECT trxn_numeric, NTILE(15) OVER (ORDER BY trxn_numeric) AS batch_number
  FROM corrected
)
GROUP BY batch_number
ORDER BY batch_number;


Or, if the table can't be fixed, just don't use "-1"? If the OP interprets the result as range=[min, max)? (If the table is already indexed on trxn_no, resorting will be expensive, and using the results will require expensive casting too.)

The data type of the column trxn_no is number and I am using Oracle 19c

Are you absolutely sure the data type is number? This is extremely unlikely. See the right sort order with NUMBER and the wrong sort order with VARCHAR2 here: https://dbfiddle.uk/iBf86VQK

Yes am 100% sure that the data type is number

@MatBailie
the table is not indexed on trxn_no

Please SELECT DUMP(trxn_no), trxn_no FROM processed_trxns FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY and show the result here.
